# How to convert mongoDB result grouped by $week to date format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to create a report where I show sum of hours weekly. I'm using mongoDB and grouping by $week.  I need to differentiate weeks by year and my report needs to have date for first day of the week and last day of the week instead of week number. Here is my pipeline.

```
let pipeline = [
{
  $match: {
    companyId,
  },
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      $week: '$date',
    },
  },
},
{
  $project: {
    companyId: '$companyId',
  },
},];
```

and here is my collection :

```
const hoursSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  personId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  jobId: Number,
  companyId: Number,
  name: String,
  date: Date,
  hours: Number,
});
```

Comment: You can use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) along with the `$group` to get the sum of `hours` weekly.

Comment: I edited my question, I was looking for a way to convert week number to date format,( first day of week & last day of week).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I ended up doing was adding year and using a function separately to extract date from week and year numbers. The pipeline looks like this:

```
let pipeline = [
    {
      $match: {
        companyId,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          week: { $week: { date: '$date' } },
          year: { $year: { date: '$date' } },
          name: '$name',
          jobTitle: '$jobTitle',
          jobId: '$jobId',
          companyId: '$companyId',
          personId: '$personId',
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        hours: { $sum: '$hours' },
      },
    },
  ];
```

I put user details in $group _id to extract information for each user. so each grouped by object of mine now has year and week and I could use [this](https://codepen.io/Venugopal46/pen/WrxdLY) to calculate date for first day and last day of the week.